# Grails 3.0x: Where did forms go?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Migrated to Grails 3.06 from 2.2x and it's a whole lot to unlearn/re-learn.  Managing with exception of _forms.gsp files which are no longer part of "generate-all"; I don't have a method to modify the HTML of specific pages outside of what's generated from the .groovy files (like adding a button to invoke a .js script, for example).  Grails docs "latest version" don't appear to really be accurate as many items appear to be deprecated or throw errors.

I tried dropping in a forms file from the 2.2x world but obviously that doesn't fly; I've hit my limit for googling for a solution and would like to poll the audience for solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eh never mind -- I can modify HTML via create.gsp files which is a departure from older versions.